# Did the Chernobyl power station's water cistern really hold $7000\:\rm m^3$?

Tags: mass, nuclear-physics, water, volume

In he HBO TV miniseries *Chernobyl*, they talk about a cistern holding 7000 cubic meters of water. That is the content of Loch Ness, the deepest lake in the UK. Would the Chernobyl reactor really hold that much water?

Comment: According to wikipedia, Lochness has volume $7.5 \text{km}^3$, not 7500 $\text{m}^3$. One $\text{km}^3$ is cube $1000~\text{m}~\times1000~\text{m}~\times1000~\text{m}$, that is $1~000~000~000\text{m}^3$.

Comment: @JánLalinský Perhaps convert comment to an answer so we don't have another question hanging without answers.

Comment: A simple google search - is this the purpose of this stack?

Comment: Related: [How large would the steam explosion at Chernobyl have been?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480113)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it doesn't appear to be about physics.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia puts the Loch Ness total volume at a total of 7.4 *cubic kilometers*, not kilo(cubic meters). When expressed in cubic meters, the 'kilo' also gets exponentiated:
$$
1\:\mathrm{km}^3 = 1 \,(1000\:\mathrm m)^3 = 10^9\:\mathrm m^3.
$$
This error in your calculation means that you are off by a factor of a million, i.e. Loch Ness is 1,000,000 times larger than (the stated size of) the Chernobyl cistern.

Generally, a volume of $V=7,000\:\rm m^3$ isn't all that big. As a rough estimate, take the cubic root, and you'll be left with
$$
L = V^{1/3} \approx 20\:\rm m,
$$
i.e. it's the volume of a cube with twenty meters to each side. That size is reasonable for a large building, not a large lake.

Comment: I don't really think this answers the question that the OP was asking (even though it does address why they probably thought to ask the question in the first place)

Comment: @DavidZ IMO the last sentence answers OP's question